# Python aiogram 3.x Ошибка

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

Пишу бота на aiogram 3. Я сделал вот такой код для оплаты, но он выдаёт ошибку и
я не знаю как её решить.
Вот текст ошибки:

> This error is raised when you try to pass additional keyword arguments to the `registrar` method in aiogram. Starting from version 2.x, registering filters is done differently and the `content_types` argument is not supported.
>
> To fix this error, you need to remove the `{'content_types'}` argument from the `registrar` method call.

Вот часть кода:

```
@dp.message(Command('buy')) 
async def buy(message: types.Message, bot:Bot):     
    if config.PAYMENT_TEST_TOKEN.split(':')[1] == 'TEST':         
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "!!!Тестовый платеж!!!")     
        await bot.send_invoice(message.chat.id,                            
                               title="Подписка на бота",                            
                               description="Активация подписки на бота на 1 месяц",                            
                               provider_token=config.PAYMENT_TEST_TOKEN,                            
                               currency="rub",                           
                                photo_url="https://www.aroged.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Telegram-has-a-premium-subscription.jpg",                            
                                photo_width=416,                            
                                photo_height=234,                           
                                photo_size=416,                            
                                is_flexible=False,                            
                                prices=[PRICE],                            
                                start_parameter="one-month-subscription",                            
                                payload="test-invoice-payload")


@dp.pre_checkout_query(lambda query: True) 
async def pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_q: types.PreCheckoutQuery, bot:Bot):     
    await bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_q.id, ok=True)
    
@dp.message(content_types == ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT)
async def successful_payment(message: types.Message, bot:Bot):     
    print("SUCCESSFUL PAYMENT:")     
    payment_info = message.successful_payment.to_python()     
    for k, v in payment_info.items():         
        print(f"{k} = {v}")     
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Платеж на сумму {message.successful_payment.total_amount // 100} {message.successful_payment.currency} прошел успешно!!!")
```

Comment: Читай внимательнее ошибку, в ней всё сказанно, замени content_types == ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT на F.successful_payment, в aiogram 3x поменяли magic filters, советую ознакомиться https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/dispatcher/filters/magic_filters.html

Answer (score 0):

Замените

```
@dp.message(content_types == ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT)
```

на

```
@dp.message(F.successful_payment)
```